# Prove $\exists x P(x) \wedge \forall y(P(y) \rightarrow Q(y)) \rightarrow \exists z Q(z)$ is a tautology

Tags: logic, solution-verification, predicate-logic

Is this proof correct?

Proof by contradiction

$\phi = \exists x P(x) \wedge \forall y(P(y) \rightarrow Q(y)) $
$\psi = \exists z Q(z) $

1. Assume $\phi \rightarrow \psi$ is not a tautology
2. Then there exists an interpretation $I$ such that $I(\phi) = true$ and $I(\psi) = false$
3. Under this interpretation, $I(\psi) = true$ as:

$\quad\quad $ $\phi \vDash \psi$ (If the premises are true, then there will exist an element with property Q)

4. A contradiction is reached
5. Therefore, $\phi \rightarrow \psi$ is a tautology

Comment: I think this is an easy application of existential instantiation on $\exists x P(x)$ to get $P(a)$ then you can use universal instantiation on and modus pones $\forall x P(x)\rightarrow Q(x)$ to get $Q(a)$ and finally existential generalization

Comment: [Here's a useful tool.](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#%E2%88%83x%20P(x)%20%E2%88%A7%E2%88%80y(P(y)%20%E2%86%92Q(y))%20%E2%86%92%E2%88%83%20z%20Q(z))

Comment: @aldodecristo Thanks. I did the natural deduction proof of $\phi \vdash \psi $ and indeed it is quite straight forward. The problem I'm working on hints towards a semantic proof, which i failed to mention.